# Not able to open android app

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

```
<input type="button" value="Open App" id="btnOpenapp" visible="true" onClick="location.href ='intent://?ret=http://54.169.8.47/app/webond.html?AppData=#Intent;scheme=amsytplus;package=com.amsyt.webond;S.browser_fallback_url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amsyt.bookwise;end'"  />
```

Try to open app by above URL but it always redirect to app link not opening my application.

Comment: Did you add this tag <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> in menifest on project

Comment: @RahulChokshi yes.